# Assign observations to a group based on another vector in the same R dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to assign areas to observations in a dataframe in R, based on grid square IDs. I have the following dataframe (*df*):

```
      year month  square
    1 2000     2      A1
    2 2000     2      B2
    3 2000     2      H5
    4 2000     2      J9
    5 2000     2      A2
    6 2000     3      N8
    7 2000     3      M9
    8 2000     3      C7
```

I'd like to add another column for "area", assigning each observation to "North", "East", "South" or "West" based on the grid square. I've tried the following *for* loops which didn't do anything,

```
    for(i in 1:length(df$square))  {
    for(j in 1:length(N)) {
    if(df$square[i]==N[j]){
    df$area[i]=="N"}
    }
    }

    for(i in 1:length(df$square))  {
    if(any(df$square==N)==T){
    df$area[i]=="North"}
    }
```

Where "N" is an object I created containing the squares located in the north, i.e.:

```
    N <- c("A1","A2","B2")
```

I did find the following related question, but I'm wondering if it's different when characters are involved: [Assign a group number based on another column by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703189/assign-a-group-number-based-on-another-column-by-group-in-r)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try building a lookup "data.frame" mapping each square to its area and, then, use something like `lookup$area[match(df$square, lookup$square)]`

Comment: `df$area = NA; df$area[df$square %in% N] = "N"` will work for the single vector you show. The best way to do it would probably be to make a data frame with columns `area` and `square` as a lookup table and then just use `merge` (or `match` as pointed out above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R it is usually best to avoid loops, and especially nested loops. For this case, I prefer `sapply()`.

```
N <- c("A1","A2","B2")
#assume these are the other designations
S <- c("H5", "J9")
E <- c("N8","M9")
W <- c("C7")

mydat$area<- sapply(mydat$square, function (x){
  if (x %in% N)  return("North")
  if (x %in% S)  return("South")
  if (x %in% E)  return("East")
  if (x %in% W)  return("West")
  else NA
  }) 
mydat

year month square  area
2000     2     A1 North
2000     2     B2 North
2000     2     H5 South
2000     2     J9 South
2000     2     A2 North
2000     3     N8  East
2000     3     M9  East
2000     3     C7  West
```

When you start having large data sets, `*apply()` functions will be much faster than loops in R.

Comment: This worked well - as you say, good for large datasets. I should probably have mentioned in my question the dataset actually had >20000 rows! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining vectors like `N`, I recommend a second `data.frame` pairing squares with areas:

```
df <- data.frame(year = 2000,
                 month = c(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 square = c("A1", "B2", "H5", "J9", "A2", "N8", "M9", "C7"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
areas <- data.frame(square = c("A1", "A2", "B1", "H5", "J9", "M9", "N8"),
                    area = c("N", "N", "N", "W", "E", "S", "S"),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

With that, just do a merge:

```
merge(df, areas, by = "square", all.x = TRUE)
#   square year month area
# 1     A1 2000     2    N
# 2     A2 2000     2    N
# 3     B2 2000     2 <NA>
# 4     C7 2000     3 <NA>
# 5     H5 2000     2    W
# 6     J9 2000     2    E
# 7     M9 2000     3    S
# 8     N8 2000     3    S
```

(The `NA`s are because of in incomplete `areas` definition.)

Answer (score 0):

```
d <- data.frame(year = rep(2000, 8), month = rep(3,8),
            square = c("A1", "B2", "H5", "J9", "A2", "N8", "M9", "C7"))

N <- c("A1","A2","B2")

for(i in 1:nrow(d))  {
    if (d$square[i] %in% N) {
        d$area[i] <- "North"
    }
    else (
        d$area[i] <- "Somewhere Else"
    )
}
```

layer in else if() statements in the for loop for other cardinal direction id vectors